# How to convert SQL select queries to korzh easy query data model and export to XML

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml, easyquery

Previously I was using **KORZH Easy Query Data Model** builder for AD-Hoc reporting. I was using Data Model Editor tool for that manually. Now I am using dev express query builder to generate queries but my previous AD-Hoc reporting requires XML based queries generated using Data Model Editor tool. How can I generate XML like data model editor. Is any way to convert SQL query to KORZH easy query data model XML.

Comment: The SQL Server scripting language is not great for generating XML data. Much easier to do with c# Net XML libraries.  So I would use Entity in c# to build models in c# classes and then serialize the classes to xml.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going from SQL to Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) first.  Then AST to EasyQuery XML.

Its not an easy problem.  I would move back to EasyQuery or change 100% to something that works with dev express.

[Sql Parser from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsql150parser?view=sql-dacfx-150)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31825081)